# Cannot use inheritance in MVC, PHP

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

please help me with the following issue.
I got DefaultController with DefaultModel :

```
Class DefaultController {
    public function __construct(DefaultModel $model){
         $this->model = $model;
    }
}
```

And I got AdminController thats going to inherit from DefaultController but It has own personal Model called AdminModel :

```
Class AdminController extends DefaultController {
    public function __construct(AdminModel $model){
         parent::__contstruct(DefaultModel $model);
         $this->model = $model;
    }
}
```

I got the following error : Unknown variable DefaultModel.
If I undo DefaultModel got next error: got AdminModel, expected DefaultModel.

Please help me with this issue,
Thanks a lot,
Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not include the type when you call `parent::__construct`. Your constructor should look like this:

```
public function __construct(AdminModel $model){
     parent::__contstruct($model);
     $this->model = $model;
}
```

Comment: Doing this a have an error called:
Expected DefaultModel, got AdminModel

Comment: Errr... parent::__construct($model); (without the extra t) would be better?

Comment: If your `AdminModel` extends `DefaultModel`, it won't give you an error. If you don't want to use inheritance for the models, you can declare an interface for models instead.